# Sass concatenate #ID selector

Tags: sass

I want to prefix all IDs with Sass, so I tried:

```
$idprefix: prefix-;

##($idprefix)something {
}
```

But Sass (3.5.2 Bleeding Edge) gives me the Error: Invalid CSS after "#": expected id name, was "#($idprefix)som..."

Then I replaced the first # with a . (as seen here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/use-sass-variable-selector/)

```
.#($idprefix)something {
}
```

But it gives the same error.

Comment: You have to use `{` not `(` for interpolation: `#{$idprefix}` not `#($idprefix)`

Comment: @ReSedano: Thanks, that was the solution!